# Loading a line from a file into a linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I was hoping to get some help with a function I am writing.
In a separate header file, I have a struct. it is structured as follows:

```
typedef struct data{
    int id;                 
    char name[100];             
    char text[200];         
   
    struct data *next;  
}listData;
```

Using this struct, I am trying to populate the list with data from a file, which has a format of

id, name, text\n

My function prototype looks as follows:

```
void loadDataFromFile(listData** dataList);
```

Because of the commas in between each of the variables, I am not sure how to read the file into the list without getting an error.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Share the code you've written so far. struct & function prototype looks fine.

Comment: Read line with `fgets`. Parse line, maybe with `strtok`, maybe `sscanf`, maybe char by char. Put parsed data into a struct. Add struct to linked list.

Answer (score -1):

What you could try doing is reading the file, and then read line by line, in which you can then split up the line by the comma with strtok()

```
char read_buffer[] = "File content";
char * file_content = read_buffer;
while(file_content) {
    char * next_line = strchr(file_content, '\n');
    if (next_line) *next_line = '\0'; // Terminate next line so you can read the current line
    char * answer = strtok(file_content, ","); // Split the current line by comma
    answer = strtok(NULL, ","); // Gets the next value after first comma, do with rest on the line

    if (nextLine) *nextLine = '\n'; // Bring the next line back
    config = nextLine ? (nextLine+1) : NULL; // Config is equal to the next line (if it exists)

}
```

Comment: You cannot write to a string lieteral and you cannot use `strtok` on a string literal, that yields undefined behaviour.

Comment: @pablo While still a bad thing to do in an example code, I think the string literal just represents file contents here.

Comment: ...edited to fix the  string literal write issue.

Comment: @hyde we can only judge by the code that has been posted. Everything else is speculation, and unless you have real crystal ball that works, we have to take the presented code at face value, specially if you are giving an answer.

Comment: @Pablo If we take "reading the file" and "file content" at face value, it means file content, so not a string literal. But feel free to roll back the edit.

Comment: @hyde Why would I roll back the edit? That would made the code incorrect.